# TypeError: (0 , _react.useEffect) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, parceljs

when in the development environment, my app works just fine.
When in the production environment it crashes with the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _react.useEffect) is not a function`

It happens in a file I created where I import React and useEffect like so:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

const X = () => {
  useEffect(() => { ... })

  ...
}
```

adding a console.log just below this line confirms that useEffect is indeed undefined when in production and the expected function when in dev.

I checked my package.json, yarn.lock & node_modules for any react or react-dom version that might be under 16.8.0 where useEffect was introduced. But everything is 16.13.1 and they are the main dependency and I did try to clean my yarn cache, delete node_modules & yarn.lock, and re-install.

I tried adding and removing it from `peerDependencies` without success.

I put in a check to make sure there are not 2 separate versions of React running, but saving `window.React1 = React` inside the library and `window.React2 = React` inside my application and checking

`window.React1 === window.React2` it was true, so that's not it either.

Lastly, I also tried to alias React to the specific one in node_modules, but without any luck.

The only solution I've found that works are if I import it like so:

```
import React from 'react';

const X = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => { ... })
  ...
}
```

But this should be exactly the same as using a destructured import?
If I do explicitly use React.useEffect it also forces me to change all of my other useState and useEffect hooks to `React.useSate` and `React.useEffect`

The next error just becomes: `TypeError: (0 , _react.useState) is not a function` in another file where I use React hooks.

I want to solve the problem not implement a workaround.

I use `microbundle` to bundle my library using React.
I use `parcel-bundler` to import the React-component and render it in a dev environment (directly from src) or prod (the bundled library)

The bundled version I use is bundled with .mjs

I checked the output of the minified .mjs bundle as well and inside React is imported like this:

`import ue,{useEffect as pe,useState as fe}from"react";`

Which looks fine to me.

What I really don't understand is how a restructured import would break it, but just doing React.useEffect would work just fine?

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "1.1.4",
  "repository": "git@github.com:xxx/xxx.git",
  "author": "xxx",
  "license": "MIT",
  "source": "src/index.ts",
  "main": "dist/bundle.js",
  "umd:main": "dist/bundle.umd.js",
  "module": "dist/bundle.mjs",
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/@xxx"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "microbundle",
    "dev": "parcel ./test-app/dev/index.html --port 3000",
    "start": "parcel ./test-app/serve/index.html --port 3000",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -s ./public -c .storybook --ci",
    "prepublishOnly": "yarn build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@api-platform/admin": "2.1.0",
    "@api-platform/api-doc-parser": "0.8.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.10",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@react-keycloak/web": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/pluralize": "^0.0.29",
    "google-geocoder": "0.2.1",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "keycloak-js": "^9.0.3",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "lodash.omit": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.set": "4.3.2",
    "notistack": "0.9.9",
    "papaparse": "^5.2.0",
    "parcel-bundler": "1.12.4",
    "polished": "^3.5.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-admin": "3.4.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-is": "16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "4.0.5",
    "styled-components": "5.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-export-default-from": "7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.9.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.9.4",
    "@storybook/addon-a11y": "5.3.18",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "5.3.18",
    "@storybook/addon-info": "5.3.18",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "5.3.18",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "5.3.18",
    "@storybook/addon-storyshots": "5.3.18",
    "@storybook/addon-storysource": "5.3.18",
    "@storybook/addon-viewport": "5.3.18",
    "@storybook/react": "5.3.18",
    "@testing-library/react": "^10.0.3",
    "@types/jsonld": "1.5.1",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.149",
    "@types/node": "13.11.1",
    "@types/papaparse": "5.0.3",
    "@types/react-redux": "7.1.7",
    "@types/recompose": "^0.30.7",
    "@types/styled-components": "5.1.0",
    "@welldone-software/why-did-you-render": "4.0.7",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "5.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "4.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "1.10.7",
    "lodash.get": "4.4.2",
    "lodash.uniq": "4.5.0",
    "microbundle": "0.11.0",
    "openapi-types": "1.3.5",
    "parcel-plugin-static-files-copy": "2.3.1",
    "pluralize": "^8.0.0"
  },
  "alias": {
    "jsonld": "./node_modules/jsonld/dist/jsonld.js"
  },
  "staticFiles": {
    "staticPath": "public",
    "watcherGlob": "**"
  }
}
```

Also worth noting, it's only React I'm having this problem with. All my other restructured imports work just fine.

Comment: Using named imports in no way the same as referencing members of the default export. My guess is that, at development time, you have some additional loader in place that's doing some shenanigans to work around legacy compatibility issues between module loaders

Comment: can you try the `global` flag `--globals react=React` and adding React as peer dependencies <- Although it might not be a proper fix. Look at this issue: https://github.com/developit/microbundle/issues/537 it looks like coming from `yarn`

Comment: Could you also try to install microbundle@next to see if that one worked? just to check if it is indeed the current microbundle version issue

Comment: If you're using TypeScript, you might also want to look into this issue: https://github.com/developit/microbundle/issues/564

Comment: Why are you using the module `bundle.mjs` instead of the main `bundle.js`?

Comment: Do you use code splitting?

Comment: My guess is it happened because of using `microbundler` instead of `react-scripts` for production build, or something altered bundler configurations in a bad way. I want to draw your attention react hooks names should start with `use` and may be in this line `import ue,{useEffect as pe,useState as fe}from"react";` which useEffect imported as `pe` something went wrong with react. So, had you tried build with `create-react-app` and `react-scripts`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seem that `microbundler` does not tolerate to React. This one create bundle that attempt to use `react` from global scope, instead `React` that really exposed.

For the same reason your workaround with `React.useEffect` works as expected, just imagine that it looks like `window.React.useEffect`.

Here is an example of a primitive application:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

/**
 * necessary workaround, microbundle use `h` pragma by default,
 * that undefined when use React
 * another option is to make build with option --jsx
 * @example microbundle --globals react=React --jsx React.createElement
 * yes, yet another workaround
*/
window.h = React.createElement;

const X = () => {
  const [A, B] = useState('world');

  useEffect(() => {
    B('MLyck');
  }, [])

  return `Hello ${A}`;
}

ReactDOM.render(<X />, document.querySelector('react-app'));
```

After bundling with just `microbundle` it completely broken, but when you try to bundle with

```sh
microbundle --globals react=React
```

as correctly suggest @Jee Mok, it will produce correct bundle.
I hope comments will explain what happened.

```js
!function (e, t) {
  "object" == typeof exports && "undefined" != typeof module ?
    t(require("react-dom"), require("react")) :
    "function" == typeof define && define.amd ?
      define(["react-dom", "react"], t) :
      t(e.ReactDOM, e.React);
  /*
  String above is core of problem,
  in case you try to bundle without options `--globals react=React`
  it will looks like: `t(e.ReactDOM, e.react);`
  Obviously `react` is not defined in `e` e.g. `this` e.g. `window`
  due to react expose self as `React`
   */
}(this, function (e, t) {
  e = e && e.hasOwnProperty("default") ? e.default : e, window.h = ("default" in t ? t.default : t).createElement, e.render(h(function () {
    var e = t.useState("world"), n = e[0], r = e[1];
    return t.useEffect(function () {
      r("MLyck");
    }, []), "Hello " + n;
  }, null), document.querySelector("react-app"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

    <react-app></react-app>
```

And, by the way, "restructured import " not at all to blame.

Comment: I have the same problem using Webpack instead of Microbundle. I think the problem is the same: the bundle attempt to use `react` from global scope, instead `React` .
Any idea how I can solve that with Webpack?

Answer (score 5):

You can fix it by doing:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
```

Answer (score 4):

This answer is not for the exact circumstances of the asker, but a possible (albeit very unlikely) solution to the error message in the question title. Since this page is the only result on Google about the error message, I wanted to add this, just in case it helped someone.

---

I encountered this error too, but I am not using `microbundle`; I'm using plain old `create-react-app` with no modifications or anything fancy. The error was only happening in production builds; local development worked fine.

After bashing my head against the wall for an hour, I finally noticed that somehow my IDE had incorrectly auto-imported `useEffect` like this:

```
import { useEffect } from "react/cjs/react.development";
```

instead of this:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
```

Check to make sure your imports are all correct.

I figured this out by taking the specific minified code my browser was complaining about -- in my case, `TypeError: (0 , m.useEffect) is not a function` -- finding it with `ctrl+f` in my `/build/static/main.blah.js` file, observing what code was near it, then tracing it back to the original source file in `/src` where I discovered the bad import.

Answer (score 4):

i got this error message, but in my case was:

```
import React, {useEffect } from "react";
```

try this

```
useEffect( ()=>{} , []  )
```

instead of

```
useEffect=( ()=>{} , []  )
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was syntactical. This was when calling the useEffect function into the DOM incorrectly:

Wrong way **doubling up on braces**:

`onInput={{inputHandler}}`

Correct way:

`onInput={inputHandler}`

Answer (score 0):

In my cases, i work with Next.js. And i've imported hooks { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";. So they are both working fine, but when i add useEffect. I have error, like in the question. So, to fix . I made import
useEffect from 'react', but { useDispatch, useSelector } are still import from 'react-redux'. I'm not sure thats a good practice, to import hooks from different library. But it fixed issues. Hope i help someone.

Comment: Note: that useEffect hook did not exist in 'react-redux' library.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with `TypeError: (0 , _react.useLocation) is not a function` (and searching for that error message returned this SO question near the top of the results).

I was importing `useLocation()` from `'react'` instead of from `'react-router-dom'`. Rookie mistake, but it could happen to someone else, so I thought I would mention it here.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was

```
import { useEffect } from "@react-native-community/hooks";
```

Later I changed it to

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
```

and it worked.