# Webpack (in prod) bundles give error: TypeError: (0 , tm.useEffect) is not a function...why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-hooks, babeljs

My React app is using Webpack + Babel. When I compile in development everything works perfectly well.

When I bundle for production ("npm run build") and upload the bundle in prod, an error appear in the console:

[image: Webpack bundle error]

Why? I found a similar question but didn't find an answer : [related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61348714/typeerror-0-react-useeffect-is-not-a-function)

Here's my `webpack.prod.js` config:

```
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { ProvidePlugin, web } = require("webpack");
const cleanPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",

  devtool: "source-map",
  entry: ["regenerator-runtime/runtime.js", "./src/index.js"],

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "index_bundle.js",

  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jsx|js)$/,
        exclude: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,

        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: {
          loader: "svg-url-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  resolve: {
    alias: { react: path.resolve("./node_modules/react") },
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "src/index.html",
      title: "Production",
    }),
    //no need to import react in every module
    new ProvidePlugin({
      React: "react",
    }),
    //erase "dist" bundle before every "npm run build"
    new cleanPlugin.CleanWebpackPlugin(),
  ],

  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        parallel: true,
      }),
    ],
  },
  
};
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "timerfrontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack serve --config webpack.config.js",
    "create": "webpack -w",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.3.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.65.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.5.6",
    "@apollo/link-context": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^4.0.0",
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^1.8.0",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.6",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.17",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.5",
    "npm-force-resolutions": "^0.0.10",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
    "svg-url-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "description": "",
  "resolutions": {
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "graphql": "16.1.0"
  }
}
```

The console error point to that index bundle.js:2 code :

[image: bundle.js code break]

The error refer to this react component in my project:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import { NEW_SESSION, newSessionVariables } from "../../graphql/newSession.js";
import { GET_TOTAL_SESSIONS_TODAY } from "../../graphql/getSessions";
import dayjs from "dayjs";

const sessionCreateDate = dayjs().format("M-D-YYYY");

const TimerAtZero = ({ timerState, toggle, user = { name: "" } }) => {
  const [createSession, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(NEW_SESSION, {
    refetchQueries: [
      { query: GET_TOTAL_SESSIONS_TODAY, variables: { sessionCreateDate, userName: user.name } },
    ],
  });
  const { endSession } = toggle;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (timerState.seconds === 0 && timerState.minutes === 0) {
      endSession();
      createSession(newSessionVariables(user.name, timerState));
    }
  }, [timerState.seconds, timerState.minutes]);

  if (loading) return <div>Submitting...</div>;
  if (error) return <div>{error.message}</div>;
  return null;
};

export default TimerAtZero;
```

Comment: did you try this one [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62899018/useeffect-typeerror-e-is-not-a-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62899018/useeffect-typeerror-e-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Thx but the error I'm facing occur in production (after bundling with webpack). The question you linked is about how to use useEffect. My app works fine in development, only when I use webpack to bundle it for production that somehow it doesn't read properly React hook.

Comment: Can you also share the code that generates this error? So we can replicate your error.

Comment: @Amir I would be hard to share the entire project code, but I added the component that webpack says break + image of the console error. Does that help?

Comment: I have tried different configurations with your code, but I wasn't able to reproduce the error. Maybe trying with `optimization.minimize = false` can lead us to the real error.

Comment: @Amir By setting `optimization.minimize = false`, I realize I identified the wrong component as breaking....duh. I added `React.useEffect()` to the appropriate component and everything works. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that helped. There is also another thing I wanted to mention. I don't know what is your use case exactly, but maybe you don't need `resolve` for react. Also, I'm not sure using `ProvidePlugin` is a good practice, I personally prefer to `import` react every time with the help of a snippet in the editor. Tell me if you want me to expand about this on a new answer.

Comment: @Amir Yes please do, I will grant you the bounty. Also, I'd love to see how you work without `ProvidePlugin` as I thought everyone used it. Why I encountered my problem I still don't know...

PS: I removed `resolved` (I should edit the question) but this wasn't causing my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't use minified version for finding bugs, it usually shows issues in a weird way that doesn't make sense. Using `optimization.minimize = false` in webpack can help with that.

There are cases to look out for when you are using webpack `ProvidePlugin`.

The tools that you use for linting, type checking, analyzers, ... should also be configured to detect that global import, which is more work and maintenance in other config files.

For example for `eslint` you can do this:

```js
{
    "globals": {
        "ReactDOM": true
    }
}
```

If you choose to change your bundler someday, then you are gonna have a hard time if the other bundler doesn't support something like `ProvidePlugin`.

And also new developers might get confused at first if they didn't know about `ProvidePlugin`. But everyone knows about the `import`!

Considering these issues, in the end, it's up to you and your project need to see if it's worth using `ProvidePlugin` or not.

If you are using `ProvidePlugin` only because it's hard to type import react every time, then you need to use snippets in your editor. For example, in VSCode there is a [plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets) that has this kind of snippets. Or you can create your own snippets if you want.

Comment: Thanks Amir, by setting optimization.minimize = false, I realize I identified the wrong component as breaking....duh. Learned something new about debugging! I added React.useEffect() to the appropriate component and everything works. `ProvidePlugin` was messing with the compiler I guess...

Answer (score 1):

Pointing an alias to a node module is an error. Just remove your `resolve` entry and everything should run fine.

```js
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { ProvidePlugin, web } = require("webpack");
const cleanPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",

  devtool: "source-map",
  entry: ["regenerator-runtime/runtime.js", "./src/index.js"],

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "index_bundle.js",

  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jsx|js)$/,
        exclude: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,

        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: {
          loader: "svg-url-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "src/index.html",
      title: "Production",
    }),
    new ProvidePlugin({
      React: "react",
    }),
    new cleanPlugin.CleanWebpackPlugin(),
  ],

  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        parallel: true,
      }),
    ],
  },
  
};
```

If it still crash, remove the `ProvidePlugin` and manually import React in the impacted files.

Comment: I did remove the `resolve` entry and still get an error but different this time: 

```TypeError: (0 , nm.useEffect) is not a function
    at om (index_bundle.js:formatted:13740)
    at la (index_bundle.js:formatted:23968)
    at Wl (index_bundle.js:formatted:27241)
    at $s (index_bundle.js:formatted:26444)
    at Is (index_bundle.js:formatted:26437)
    at Os (index_bundle.js:formatted:26421)
    at vs (index_bundle.js:formatted:26185)
```

Also, removing ProvidePlugin and importing `react` in all files seems like a workaround? Would be nice to solve it at the source...

Comment: I also tried to add `import react` in the impacted files as a workaround and somehow it didn't work.